# Unfortunately your <Project name> has stopped working.

Tags: java, android

i am a really NOOB and new coder. I started learning Java and recently created this application on eclipse. It is a dollar to euros converter. Everytime i try to run the code on eclipse i get error saying the application has stopped working.

```
TextView dollars;
TextView euros;
RadioButton dtoe;
RadioButton etod;
Button calculate;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dollars = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.dollars);
    euros = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.euros);

    dtoe = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.dtoe);
    etod = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.euros);

    calculate = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    if (dtoe.isChecked()){
        convertDollarsToEuros();
    }
    if (etod.isChecked()){
        convertEurosToDollars();
    }
}

protected void convertDollarsToEuros(){

    double val = Double.parseDouble(dollars.getText().toString());
    euros.setText(Double.toString(val*0.67));
}

protected void convertEurosToDollars(){
    double val = Double.parseDouble(euros.getText().toString());
    dollars.setText(Double.toString(val*0.67));
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is throwing an exception somewhere. Look at the logcat output (open the view using Window -> Show View if it's not already showing). There should be an exception showing where the problem occurred. It's easiest to do this using an emulator rather than a real device.

Comment: Try to make null checks for getText() before converting to String in both convertDollarsToEuros() and convertEurosToDollars(). And also make sure to use both RadioButtons in RadioGroup.

Answer (score 1):

Without the logcat it's only an educated guess, but look at this line:

```
etod = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.euros);
```

Are you sure you're using the right id? It's the same as the one you use for the `TextView` above. You're probably throwing a `ClassCastException`, because you're trying to use it as a `RadioButton`.

Unrelated, but your conversion logic also seems wrong. You can't expect *both* of the conversions to be `(val * 0.67)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to guess without a logcat. But I assume there's an NPE being thrown. Most likely it's from

```
dollars.getText().toString()
```

and

```
euros.getText().toString()
```

I suggest you to include a null check before apply .toString().

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going to Window > Show View > Console, depending on the error, it will sometimes give you links to the lines in the classes that are causing problems.